# Why can't we plot this simple text against values in R?

Tags: r, plot

I gleaned some information from an HTML table online using the XML package:

```
library("XML")
library("RCurl")
library("rlist")
theurl = getURL("http://www.victoria2wiki.com/Countries_table", .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl, as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

`tables` now holds a `list` containing information from the table on the page. 
Then we convert this `list` to a `dataframe` by using:

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, tables)
```

`names(df)` shows

```
[1] " Country\n"    " Tier\n"       " Population\n" " Literacy\n"
```

`df[,3]` shows all of the population numbers. We tried to plot it using:

`> plot(df[,3])`, but the graph is incorrect and shows population numbers on X-axis and does not make sense.

How do we plot country names against their population given our simple R data frame? What we want is a simple line plot of populations on Y-axis and names of countries on X-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
library("XML")
library("RCurl")
library("rlist")
theurl = getURL("http://www.victoria2wiki.com/Countries_table", .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl, as.data.frame = TRUE)

# tables is a list with two elements
# The data frame is stored in the second element of this list
df <- tables[[2]]
colnames(df) <- c("Country", "Tier", "Population", "Literacy")

# Population is a factor and needs to be converted into a numeric vector
par(mar=c(3,7,1,1))
barplot(as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Population)), 
        names.arg=df$Country, horiz=T, las=1, cex.names=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Changing the class from `factor` to `numeric` in `as.numeric(df[,3])` is not cleanly transforming the population numbers. For instance, China in the resulting graph has a population of around 50, but is a factor with value "207,120,000" in `df`.

Comment: @GeorgeWood I agree. I modify the code in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Something like this should work: `df <- tables[[2]];
colnames(df) <- c("Country", "Tier", "Population", "Literacy");
df$Population <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Population))`

Comment: @GeorgeWood Thank you !